# Why didn't the Castellan regenerate in "The Five Doctors"?

Tags: doctor-who

In "The Five Doctors," the Time Lord known as "The Castellan" is shot and killed.  He doesn't regenerate, but...shouldn't he have?  Unless he was on his twelfth regeneration, but no one comments on this.

Have other Time Lords ever been shown to be permanently killed without ceremony like this?

Comment: I don't remember if it's been *shown* on-screen, but there have certainly been *references* to other Time Lords being permanently killed without ceremony. Missy in "The Magician's Apprentice", for instance, or the Eleventh Doctor in "The Impossible Astronaut". It's certainly possible to kill a Time Lord permanently if you know what you're doing.

Comment: In this case it was an ordinary-looking gun that did the trick.  He was shot on Gallifrey by another Time Lord, so I suppose it could have had the effect of killing him permanently, but if so it's odd that no one would comment on it.  It seems more as if the writers just forgot that Time Lords regenerate.

Comment: @Sean - Was the gun of Gallifreian design?

Comment: I think it's mentioned near the end of the *Sound of Drums* arc that a Time Lord can also choose not to regenerate - commit suicide, essentially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### He was killed with the right weapon

It’s very possible to kill a Time Lord without regeneration, under the right circumstances. It generally involves killing them very quickly, or with the right tools. This being *Doctor Who*, there’s also undoubtedly a “timey-wimey” factor to explain any apparent inconsistencies. For example:

- The Master suggested she could have been killed by numerous snipers, if they shot precisely enough to kill her very quickly.

  > MISSY : Okay, cutting to the chase. Not dead, back, big surprise,
  >   never mind. I’m in a lovely little square in one of your, oh, I don’t
  >   know, hot countries. There’s a light breeze coming from the east, this
  >   coffee is a buzz-monster in my brain, and I’m going to need eight
  >   snipers.
  >
  > KATE: Eight what?
  >
  > MISSY : Three for each heart, and two for my brain stem. You’ll have
  >   to switch me off fast, before I can regenerate. How fast can you get
  >   here? Ooo, I’ll need to arrange you a flight corridor.
  >
  > <sub>*Doctor Who*, “The Magician’s Apprentice”</sub>
- The Doctor was killed quickly enough by an explosion (or a flood) that he could not regenerate:

  > HARRIS: The Doctor is dead. Must have happened too fast for him to
  >   regenerate. Escort the ambulance back to UNIT base.
  >
  > <sub>*Doctor Who*, “Turn Left”</sub>

So if the Castellan was killed with something that killed him so quickly that he couldn’t regenerate, he’d be done for, even if the weapon was rather mundane.

On the other hand, there were certain things that could kill a Time Lord slowly, without triggering regeneration, such as the Veil in “Heaven Sent.”

In any case, the Castellan was killed by a *staser*, some models of which seemed to be able to kill Time Lords quickly, and without triggering regeneration, as suggested in the prose story (perhaps somewhat lower canon than the television series) “The Ancestor Cell”.

It only makes sense that if there are weapons capable of bypassing regeneration, that Time Lords will use them.

Other versions don’t (such as when the Doctor shot the General in “Hell Bent), or perhaps certain settings on the same models that can be lethal.